# How in R group data by date and smooth them by moving average

Tags: r, grouping, smoothing, moving-average

I want to group daily data from Google Trends into weekly observations and smooth them by 7-day centered moving average? How can I do this? In which order?

Should I first group data? Or should I use centered moving average on daily data?

This is my data:

```
dput(multiTimeline)
structure(list(day = structure(c(1598400000, 1598486400, 1598572800, 
1598659200, 1598745600, 1598832000, 1598918400, 1599004800, 1599091200, 
1599177600, 1599264000, 1599350400, 1599436800, 1599523200, 1599609600, 
1599696000, 1599782400, 1599868800, 1599955200, 1600041600, 1600128000, 
1600214400, 1600300800, 1600387200, 1600473600, 1600560000, 1600646400, 
1600732800, 1600819200, 1600905600, 1600992000, 1601078400, 1601164800, 
1601251200, 1601337600, 1601424000, 1601510400, 1601596800, 1601683200, 
1601769600, 1601856000, 1601942400, 1602028800, 1602115200, 1602201600, 
1602288000, 1602374400, 1602460800, 1602547200, 1602633600, 1602720000, 
1602806400, 1602892800, 1602979200, 1603065600, 1603152000, 1603238400, 
1603324800, 1603411200, 1603497600, 1603584000, 1603670400, 1603756800, 
1603843200, 1603929600, 1604016000, 1604102400, 1604188800, 1604275200, 
1604361600, 1604448000, 1604534400, 1604620800, 1604707200, 1604793600, 
1604880000, 1604966400, 1605052800, 1605139200, 1605225600, 1605312000, 
1605398400, 1605484800, 1605571200, 1605657600, 1605744000, 1605830400, 
1605916800, 1606003200, 1606089600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), football = c(36, 36, 41, 60, 45, 38, 38, 39, 
43, 49, 70, 49, 44, 46, 50, 62, 71, 92, 96, 61, 51, 45, 50, 58, 
87, 81, 54, 50, 43, 49, 58, 97, 84, 55, 48, 41, 51, 56, 94, 83, 
51, 47, 46, 49, 62, 97, 84, 51, 55, 51, 47, 52, 96, 79, 51, 49, 
42, 44, 52, 100, 82, 49, 45, 41, 42, 50, 89, 73, 48, 40, 21, 
29, 36, 75, 69, 45, 37, 39, 45, 51, 87, 69, 47, 48, 43, 37, 45, 
79, 66, 46)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Data is from 2020-08-26 to 2020-11-23.

Comment: Can you share your data using dput()

Comment: @KarthikS hi i paste screen of my data

Comment: If you use dput, we can copy it to R and manipulate it ourselves, to see if what we're saying actually works...

Comment: Ok, done, I'm new in R

Answer (score 0):

I allowed myself to use the packages `dplyr`, to make data manipulation easier, and `lubidrate`, which makes date manipualtion easy.

The code is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(week = week(day)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(average = mean(football))
```

The only function I used from `lubidrate` there was `week()`, if you're interested.

What I did was: first, I created another column (could have been the same one, though) that states the week. Note that this only works because your column was already in `date-time` format (though just `date` would have workes too, maybe even better). From that, I grouped by week and took the average. I hope I understood your question correctly and this will help.

It worked; this was the output:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 13 x 2
    week average
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    35    42  
 2    36    48.6
 3    37    69  
 4    38    60.7
 5    39    62  
 6    40    60.4
 7    41    63.4
 8    42    60.7
 9    43    59.1
10    44    54.7
11    45    44.6
12    46    55.1
13    47    52.7
```

Comment: Are week data smoothed? What if in daily data is some noise? Does week() function from lubridate smooth my data to avoid one-time shocks?

Comment: The `week()` function selects the week. As I said, the smoothing occured because it took the mean for each week. This is the exact method used with Covid data, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollmean` from `zoo` package to do all this as a one-liner.

```r
multiTimeline$rolling <- zoo::rollmean(multiTimeline$football, 7, na.pad = TRUE)

multiTimeline
#> # A tibble: 90 x 3
#>    day                 football rolling
#>    <dttm>                 <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2020-08-26 00:00:00       36    NA  
#>  2 2020-08-27 00:00:00       36    NA  
#>  3 2020-08-28 00:00:00       41    NA  
#>  4 2020-08-29 00:00:00       60    42  
#>  5 2020-08-30 00:00:00       45    42.4
#>  6 2020-08-31 00:00:00       38    43.4
#>  7 2020-09-01 00:00:00       38    44.6
#>  8 2020-09-02 00:00:00       39    46  
#>  9 2020-09-03 00:00:00       43    46.6
#> 10 2020-09-04 00:00:00       49    47.4
#> # ... with 80 more rows
```

If you want to pick out the smoothed average for each week from Saturday to Friday, just use `filter` to select only Tuesdays. This will give you the 7-day average from the previous Saturday to the following Friday.

```r
multiTimeline %>% filter(lubridate::wday(day) == 3)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    day                 football rolling
#>    <dttm>                 <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2020-09-01 00:00:00       38    44.6
#>  2 2020-09-08 00:00:00       46    56  
#>  3 2020-09-15 00:00:00       51    64.7
#>  4 2020-09-22 00:00:00       50    60.3
#>  5 2020-09-29 00:00:00       48    61.7
#>  6 2020-10-06 00:00:00       47    61.7
#>  7 2020-10-13 00:00:00       55    62.4
#>  8 2020-10-20 00:00:00       49    59  
#>  9 2020-10-27 00:00:00       45    58.4
#> 10 2020-11-03 00:00:00       40    48  
#> 11 2020-11-10 00:00:00       37    51.6
#> 12 2020-11-17 00:00:00       48    53.7
```

To show this is what you want, we can plot your data and the averaged line using ggplot:

```r
ggplot(multiTimeline, aes(day, football)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data = multiTimeline %>% filter(lubridate::wday(day) == 3), 
            aes(y = rolling), col = "red", lty = 2, size = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: After using moving average variable "rolling" is still with daily period. How can I obtain weekly data as week from saturday to friday?

Comment: @Azsb just `filter` so that only the 7 day rolling average from each Tuesday is taken. This will give you a 7-day average from the previous Saturday to the following Friday. See my update.